# Write .3gp file into .wav format python Flask server

Tags: python, flask, audio, wav, 3gp

I need to record a .3gp audio file coming from the Android front-end to be converted into .wav audio using the python Flask server back-end for further processing. Any suggested method or library to convert .3gp audio into .wav audio format?

```
audiofile = flask.request.files['file']
filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(audiofile.filename)    
audiofile.save('Audio/' + filename)
```

I'm using this code now which receives the audio file as .3gp. I need to convert this into .wav format

Comment: `ffmpeg` probably...

Comment: @MarkSetchell any source code or resources pls...

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You can also do it using ffmpeg 
**Method 1:** 
https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg#installing-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu 
bash  
`ffmpeg -i path/to/3gp.3gp path/to/wav.wav` 
or  
python (which runs bash command)

```py
import os
os.system('ffmpeg -i path/to/3gp.3gp path/to/wav.wav')
```

**Method 2:** 
Convert .3gp to .mp3 then .mp3 to .wav 
Use https://pypi.org/project/ftransc/ to convert .3gp to .mp3. Currently there is no python API for that so either use

1. bash 
   `ftransc -f mp3 filename.3gp` give the destination - check for help 
   **OR**
2. python

```py
os.system('ftransc -f mp3 filename.3gp')
```

Then use pydub https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#installation to convert .mp3 to .wav

```py
newAudio = AudioSegment.from_mp3('path/to/mp3')
newAudio.export('path/to/destination.wav', format="wav")
```

Comment: Any solutions for .3gpp ?? thx in advance :)